# Python functions with default arguments

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and playing around with function arguments. Just created a test function with following code:

```
def packer(name = 'Alpha', **kwargs):
    return(kwargs)
```

And if I call this function as:

```
dummy_packer = packer(name = 'Bravo', age = 65, beard = False)
```

The result is:

```
{'age': 65, 'beard': False}
```

The variable dummy_packer will not have **name** value at all in the result. I understand it ignored it because I have defined already at the stage of creating the function. But then why it didn't give me the default value also? Where the **name** argument is stored?

Thanks

Comment: The `name` argument is stored in the `name` variable.  `**kwargs` doesn't mean "all arguments passed by keyword", it means "all arguments passed by keyword that aren't named in the function signature".

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\*args and \*\*kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` is available to you in the function context.

```
def packer(name = 'Alpha', **kwargs):
    print('name is %s' % (name,))
    return(kwargs)
```

Comment: might be worth adding that `return dict(name=name, **kwargs)` could be used to return all arguments

Comment: Thanks, both answers helped me.

Answer (score 0):

`kwargs` refers to variable number of keyword arguments. In this case, because `name` is a defined variable, it is not included in kwargs.